# How to avoid multiple foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using a query to fetch data from the database. after fetching I am adding one extra attribute to each object but for that i have to use three foreach loop I want to avoid that foreach loop. How I can do this

here is my code for query

```
$invoices = Invoice::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
      return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)->when(!empty($request->rate_zone_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
      $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('rate_zone_id', $request->rate_zone_id);
      });
    })->withCount(['consignments_invoices'])->with(['customers:id,name', 'invoice_totals', 'consignments_invoices.charges'])->get();
```

Here I am adding one more attribute in object with help of foreach loop

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoice->setAttribute('rate_zone_income','');
        if (!empty($request->rate_zone_id)) {
        $rate_zone_income = 0;
        foreach ($invoice->consignments_invoices as $consignment) {

          foreach ($consignment->charges as $charge) {
            if ($charge->rate_zone_id == $request->rate_zone_id) {
              $rate_zone_income += $charge->income;
            }
          }
        }
        $invoice->setAttribute('rate_zone_income',$rate_zone_income);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why you think there is a problem with nested loops? You have invoices with multiple consignments so you need to use nested loop. The same with charges.

Comment: I want to manage it with query because if there are thousand of records it will take time

Comment: If it's slow, problem is elsewhere (probably in SQL query), not in nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
class Invoice extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function getRateZoneIncomeAttribute($rateZoneId = null)
    {
        if (empty($rateZoneId)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $invoice->consignments_invoices->reduce(function($rate_zone_income, $consignment) {
            return $cosignment->charges->reduce(function($rate_zone_income, $charge) {
                if ($charge->rate_zone_id == $rateZoneId) {
                    $rate_zone_income += $charge->income;
                }
                return $rate_zone_income;
            }, $rate_zone_income);
        }, 0);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but `$request` variable will be undefined in Invoice Model

Comment: Oh, right, I updated my answer so that you can pass it like this: `$invoice->rateZoneIncome($rateZoneId);`

Comment: `$charge` is also undefined

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add this one `reduce()`. I updated my answer.